# python mode of 3 columns - advice on method?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running into an issue with my project taking a looooong time - timing out. the dataframe in question is only 303 entries and looks like this:

```
   age  sex  cp  trestbps  chol  fbs  restecg  thalach  exang  oldpeak  slope  ca  thal  label_1  label_2  label_3
0    50    1   0       150   243    0        0      128      0      2.6      1   0     3        0        0        1
1    55    0   1       135   250    0        0      161      0      1.4      1   0     2        1        1        1
2    54    1   0       140   239    0        1      160      0      1.2      2   0     2        1        0        1
3    59    1   3       178   270    0        0      145      0      4.2      0   0     3        1        0        1
4    70    1   2       160   269    0        1      112      1      2.9      1   1     3        1        0        0
5    64    0   2       140   313    0        1      133      0      0.2      2   0     3        1        0        1
6    61    1   0       120   260    0        1      140      1      3.6      1   1     3        0        0        1
7    77    1   0       125   304    0        0      162      1      0.0      2   3     2        1        0        0
8    60    1   0       130   253    0        1      144      1      1.4      2   1     3        0        1        0
9    45    0   1       130   234    0        0      175      0      0.6      1   0     2        1        1        1
10   44    1   1       120   220    0        1      170      0      0.0      2   0     2        1        1        0
11   47    1   2       130   253    0        1      179      0      0.0      2   0     2        1        0        1
12   46    1   1       101   197    1        1      156      0      0.0      2   0     3        0        1        1
13   46    0   2       142   177    0        0      160      1      1.4      0   0     2        0        1        1
14   60    0   3       150   240    0        1      171      0      0.9      2   0     2        1        0        1
15   59    1   0       135   234    0        1      161      0      0.5      1   0     3        1        1        1
16   57    1   0       110   335    0        1      143      1      3.0      1   1     3        0        0        1
17   65    0   0       150   225    0        0      114      0      1.0      1   3     3        1        0        0
18   58    1   2       132   224    0        0      173      0      3.2      2   2     3        1        0        0
19   65    1   3       138   282    1        0      174      0      1.4      1   1     2        1        0        0
```

The only columns i am interested in are `label_1`, `label_2` and `label_3`.

these are binary values (0 or 1). I need a majority vote for each row, and thought i'd use the mode of the 3 columns in a for loop, like so:

```
target=[]
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    labels=data.loc[:,['label_1','label_2','label_3']]
    true_label = labels.mode(axis=1)
    
    target.append(true_label)
```

given that it is only working with 303 rows across 3 columns, i have to suspect that i did a bad job putting this together and it is taking a lot longer because it is doing something i didn't intend.

ultimately, what i am trying to do is build a target for a classifier model in which i don't currently have accurate labels for the target to train/validate the model with.

i'd love any insights, input, advice or general observations on what i might be doing wrong/should be doing differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mode` accepts `axis` option, which you already utilize. You don't need to loop through the length of your data (what does `i` do to the code inside the loop?). Just this is enough:

```
target = df.filter(like='label_').mode(axis=1)
```

Comment: wow - so much more simple! i really overthought that one! thanks so much!